# Apps on Sd card dissappear

Tags: sd-card

I've not had this phone for long,  but quite a few times,  more so on the last few days,  apps have been saying they are not installed of they are in the Sd card.  I don't know where on the SD card apps are stored so I haven't checked there.  But the 8gb music I have in the SD card does not dissappear.

Thanks for the help